# In react-native-video selectedVideoTrack props is not working

Tags: react-native, react-native-video, hls.js

I am using react-native-video for displaying hls video.

Video link:- https://test-streams.mux.dev/x36xhzz/x36xhzz.m3u8

As the video is in hls, I need to change the quality of the videos either manually or auto But I can't achieve this using react-native-video. I had done this for the web also using reactjs and had done quite successfully. I had also set up the exoplayer for react-native-video by adding the react-native.config.js file and pasting those codes.

```js
module.exports = {
  dependencies: {
    'react-native-video': {
      platforms: {
        android: {
          sourceDir: '../node_modules/react-native-video/android-exoplayer',
        },
      },
    },
  },
};
```

But my problem is most of the props are not working in this player. As selectedVideoTrack never work.

VideoComponet code:

```
      <Video
          ref={videoRef}
          source={{
            uri: 'https://test-streams.mux.dev/x36xhzz/x36xhzz.m3u8',
          }}
          resizeMode={'contain'}
          style={styles.fullscreenVideo}
          fullscreen={true}
          hls={true}
          rate={1.0}
          volume={1}
          muted={false}
          repeat={false}
          playInBackground={false}
          playWhenInactive={false}
          minLoadRetryCount={5}
          selectedVideoTrack={{
            type: 'resolution',
            value: 240,
          }}
          onError={(err) => {
            console.error(err);
          }}
          onSeek={(data) => {
            console.log(`seeked data `, data);
          }}
          onBuffer={(data) => {
            console.log('buffer data is ', data);
          }}
          reportBandwidth={true}
          onBandwidthUpdate={(data) => console.log('bandwidth updated', data)}
          selectedVideoTrack={{
            type: 'resolution',
            value: 360,
          }}

        />
```

If anybody can suggest me some other ways to achieve this then, please

Comment: Did you find any solution? I am facing the same issue. Please post your answer if you find any, this will help alot of developers.

Comment: no, I can't able find it.

Comment: then what you did?

Comment: we had dropped that project, so we don't explore any other options